# Is it possible to override Intel 4000 2-display limit?

Tags: laptop, usb, drivers, multiple-monitors, dell-latitude

Intel's drivers don't allow using more than two displays (laptop +1 external, or 2 external and no laptop display), though we have some docks that use DisplayLink software that overrides this and allows 3+ displays using USB (the intel drivers are blind to all but the built-in one.)

I am wondering if there is software that behaves similarly over dvi/hdmi/displayport ports that allows extra displays (even at the cost of performance/resolution/refresh rate) so that we can make use of some port replication style docks that would charge a laptop in addition.

I know the laptop can handle it as it's running two 1080p externals + builtin over usb, but it would be a shame if drivers were stopping me from doing the same with a different dock

Laptop in question is a Latitude 5530 with 4th gen 4000 chipset

Comment: you can use Displayport to overcome that limit. Intel 4000 can handle 3 external monitors via Displayport. see this link : http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN115952/en

Comment: Thanks for the article! The docks I have only have one displayport port on them. I have attempted to daisy-chain two monitors off of it (which works on HD 5500 chipset laptops), but this laptop refuses to recognize the second monitor.

Comment: check Optimus setting in BIOS it must be Enabled.